# Seleccionar varios archivos (input) en Angular 6

Tags: angular

Hola amigos quiero saber si hay una forma para seleccionar varios archivos sin que el segundo lo suplante, osea al agregar el segundo archivo el primero no se elimine masomenos que tenga este formato de vista.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]